# Adding trees or terminal words to multi-dominance structures

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm trying to add either a word or a tree to the DP node that is connected to the main tree by the wavy lines, in the same way that the V node has the expression "smokes" below it. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}
\ex.
\leavevmode\vadjust{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={sibling distance=2\baselineskip}}
\Tree [.\node(z){TP}; \edge[white]; ˜ [.T\1 T [.\node(y){DP}; \edge[white];
˜ [.V smokes ]]]]
\node (x) at (-4,-4) {DP}  ; 
\draw (x.east) to [out=0, in=180] (y.south); 
\draw (x.east) to [out=0, in=180] (z.south);
%\draw[help lines] (-4,-4) grid (4,4)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user65526 [Is this what you want?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0y07V.png)

Comment: Yay! Excellent. That's precisely what I'd like! So how's it done?

Comment: @user65526 Have you seen the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have two `\Tree` commands in one `tikzpicture` so Tikz confuses them and thinks they are just one tree. Usually this is solved by enclosing each in a separate `tikzpicture` but in your case this is not advisable. A less invading way to do the same thing is to use scopes.

In this case we'll apply the shift to the `scope` itself and not the main node of the second tree.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}
%\ex
\leavevmode\vadjust{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\tikzset{level 1+/.style={sibling distance=2\baselineskip}}
\Tree [.\node(z){TP}; \edge[white]; ˜ [.T\1 T [.\node(y){DP}; \edge[white];
˜ [.V smokes ]]]]
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[shift={(-4,-4)}]
\Tree [.\node(x){DP}; [.smokes ]] 
\end{scope}
\draw (x.east) to [out=0, in=180] (y.south); 
\draw (x.east) to [out=0, in=180] (z.south);
%\draw[help lines] (-4,-4) grid (4,4)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```